# Age questions: How to approach solving this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, mental-arithmetic

Completely foxed by this question: 
Moses is twice as old as Methusaleh was when Methusaleh was one-third as old as Moses will be when Moses is as old as Methuselah is now. The difference in their ages is 666 years. How old is Methusaleh now?

My problem is that if Methusaleh was 1/3 as old as Moses was, how come Moses age is twice that of Methusaleh? That does not now seem to make sense...
Any help appreciated...

Comment: I think 666 is a **huge** number for an age difference, but still the most standard way to proceed would be to formulate linear equations and then solve them. I think this would come under Mental Aptitude - MAT questions.

Comment: @Tusky - thanks, but these are biblical characters and the can live a number of years... I did try to formulate linear equations, but get stuck at the 1/3 and twice conditions and cannot seem to resolve them.

Comment: 1) $Met-Moses = 666$. 2) $Moses = 2 \times Met_1$. 3) $Met_1 = \dfrac 13 Moses_1$. 4) $Moses_1 = Met$.

Comment: "... but these are biblical characters and the can live a number of years..."  true, but Moses was born long after Methusalah died which was long after Methusalah was 666 so these numbers doen't work.  BUt anyhow... (One could claim it never stated these are *people* there are redwoods in the Sierra name Methusalah and Moses I believe... )

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA actually reread the sentence clearly.  $Met_1 = \frac 13 Met$.  Not $\frac 13 Moses$.  It just that nearly always these questions will do some tricky sounding but algebraically straightforward switching.  THis one didn't but just said int the most convoluted way Moses is $\frac 23$ as old as Methusalah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice "as old as Moses will be when Moses will be as old as X" is just a convoluted way of saying "X".

So  "Moses is twice as old as Methusaleh was when Methusaleh was one-third as old as (Moses will be when Moses is as old as Methuselah is now)" = "Moses is twice as old as Methusaleh was when Methusaleh was one-third as old as (Methusalah)"

Likewise "as old as Methusaleh was when Methusaleh was X" is just a convoluted way of saying "as old as X".

So "Moses is twice as old as (Methusaleh was when Methusaleh [was one-third as old as (Methusalah)])"= "Moses is twice as old as (one third as old as Methusalah)"

So if Moses is $A$ and Methusalah is $B$ then $A = 2*\frac 13 B$.  That is all this very convoluted sentence says.

THe next sentence "The difference in their ages is 666 years" is, I hope straight forward:  $|B- A| = 666$.  English language, but not math, implies $B > A$ but...

So solve $A = 2*\frac 13 B$ and $|B-A| = 666$.

Comment: You have a typo in the last line. It should be $A=2\ast\frac{1}{3}B$.

Comment: Many thanks... This now works out! Guess I should improve figuring out convoluted English sentences!!

Comment: When I heard the problem I thought the would be a  when methusalah was twice as old as *MOSES* would be problem.  It wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be Moses age and $y$ be Methusaleh age now.

The system to solve is

$$y=x+666, x=2y/3$$
The solution is 
$$ x=1332, y=1998$$
Thus the answer is $1998$

Comment: Thank you!! The real deal is figuring out the convoluted engish!